# How to make addEventListener work/Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new in js and can't understand where I made a mistake. I try to make select options switch. This is an HTML code

```
   <select id="sort">
        <option value="name">name</option>
        <option value="price">price</option>
      </select>
```

I tried using AddEventListener('change').
but it switches only manually. How to make it work automatically when I choose price or name in select?

```
let c = document.getElementById('sort');
   c.addEventListener('change', byField);
function byField(value) {
  return (a, b) => a[value] > b[value] ? 1 : -1; 
};
  data.sort(byField('price'));
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: You tell the browser to execute `byField()` when the selected option of `#sort` is changed. `byField()` returns a number and doesn't do anything else. If you expect the content of `data` to be modified, then you would need a function that does this when called, which you then use as the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it manually as `data.sort(byField('price'));`, make it dynamic by getting the `value` from event object.

`e.target.value` will give you the changed `value` of `select` HTML element.

```
let c = document.getElementById("sort");

function byField(value) {
    return (a, b) => (a[value] > b[value] ? 1 : -1);
}
c.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    data.sort(byField(e.target.value));
});
```